# How can I properly type this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types

I have this React Component:

```
const Icon = ({ icon, ...props }: { icon: keyof IconType }) => {
  const Icon = Icons[icon]
  return <Icon {...props} />
}
```

and I am trying to use it in this way:

```
<Icon icon={ordinaryString} />
```

How can I void getting this typescript error:

```
The type "string" cannot be assigned to the type "keyof IconType".
```

Comment: You will need a user-defined typeguard (aka [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)), so that it returns `str is keyof IconType`. TypeScript will then be able to infer that `icon` after the guard clause must be a key of `IconType` and not just `string`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume `ordinaryString` is type `string` since that's what the error message says.

The problem is you're supplying a string, which could be anything, but the component wants `keyof IconType`, which can't be just any string, but has to be a string matching one of the keys in `IconType`.

Either supply a string literal that matches `keyof IconType` (or variable/constant typed with `keyof IconType`), change the type of the `icon` prop in the component to `string` (but beware that latter option will mean `Icons` will need to be indexable by string).